# Fubini theorem in non classical summation methods

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation-method

I am aware that in the theory of classical infinite sums , one can not generally interchange the order of a double sum or do other infinite sum manipulations. However, these infinite sum manipulations can be valid if absolute convergence is available.

I am working on a problem , where I would like to manipulate a double infinite sum but absolute convergence need be satisfied in my context. I am under the impression that these classically illegal infinite sum manipulations can hold under less strict conditions in the context of non classical summation methods. I would be glad if someone can write an answer that discusses when interchanging the order of a double sum is allowed in the non classical setting and direct me to a place where I should read about this. Thank you a lot.

Comment: What kind of series do you want to study ? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: I cant provide an example as it is too specific to my application. However, I will be happy to see  answers that discuss fubini theorem in the context of zeta regulation summation method for example

Comment: I'm sure there are people on this site who would understand your example if you provided it. Unless it's a classified governmental project, or the definitions are nonstandard and take $500$ pages to set up, it can only benefit your post since it would make more sure the answers are more tailored to what you'd actually hope for and won't go somewhere else, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: No example, no answer.

Comment: Exchange of limits is more generally allowable if the double limit exists. For series, absolute convergence proves this, so it works for absolute convergence. It is also true that the exchange of limits can still result in the same value even if the double limit does not converge, but proving this is going to require specific information about the limits involved. Without that specific information, we cannot say if it is true in your case.

Comment: @BrunoB Yes, the formulas are too long to write. They arise as tensors of a power series coming from a differential geometric context. I only have a recursive formulas for the tensors, and to write this formula fully will probably take a page or two. Thus, I do not think it will be useful to write it